# How Do I Add A Maven Repository Other Than Central?

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I am trying to add the "selenium standalone server jar" to my maven project. I found this:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server-standalone/2.53.0
Copying the dependency is giving me a missing artifact error which probably mean my current maven settings isn't pointing to the repo that has this jar file. The url is http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-server-standalone/2.53.0/  How to I update my pom file so that I can add this dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Check maven documentation: 
https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html

```
 <project>
...
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>my-repo1</id>
      <name>your custom repo</name>
      <url>http://jarsm2.dyndns.dk</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>my-repo2</id>
      <name>your custom repo</name>
      <url>http://jarsm2.dyndns.dk</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
...
</project>
```

Comment: This is so weird. When I posted that question I was at work, I have since pulled from my git repo at my home computer changing nothing and it successfully got the files. I have no idea why it works from home but not work.

Comment: Using a different configuration in your settings.xml which might use an internal repository manager...

Comment: @atg it could be the case of proxy

Comment: @atg, many different reasons. Lack of Internet connection, proxy error maybe settings.xml in .m2 folder have has changed. You can always check system logs what happened there.

Comment: I'm starting to think it was an issue with the repo itself. I left my computer running overnight and when I returned I saw that maven successfully got the files 20 minutes after I left. So I guess the issue has been resolved.